# C1 or  C2 coverage tool for ruby 

Tags: ruby, testing, code-coverage, ruby-1.9

Is there any tool for [C1 or C2 code coverage](http://dev-logger.blogspot.com/2008/06/c0-c1-and-c2-coverage.html) for Ruby (1.9)? [SimpleCov supports only C0](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/issues/105), but maybe there is another tool.

I'm aware that a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289321/does-c1-code-coverage-analysis-exist-for-ruby) has been asked here, but it was a couple years ago and I hope that something has changed.

Answer (score 1):

No, currently there is no tool that does that.

There is also no technical limitation that avoids one to implement it, so feel free to create something at github :-)

Comment: `DeepCover` does, now.