# How can I test C1 coverage test in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, code-coverage

I want to test the C0, C1 coverages. I found `simplecov` gem for C0 , but I don't find tools for C1 coverage. May I know if there are any C1 coverage tools in ruby?

Comment: For people that might answer, see also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048340/c1-or-c2-coverage-tool-for-ruby?rq=1)